# How to run a WordPress PHP in local

Tags: php, html, wordpress, local

My friend gave me her WordPress website to run in localhost, but I never did it. I had installed the xampp server, but her website doesn't show in my local.

All she gave me was a 'wp-content' folder, a '.htacess' file and a 'site.php' file, which has HTML and PHP content inside of it. I just want to run it in my local so I can edit it for her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a lot of files and folders that are required to run wordpress. Also, site.php is not a core wordpress file.

You can download the official wordpress zip from [here](https://wordpress.org/download/) and compare it with that you have.